# Css float right issue

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` called `wrapper` which contains 2 other `<div>`s called `textbox` and `checkbox`.

I want to able to make the yellow box to go inside the wrapper.
The pink box is used as an input text field and the yellow box is used as a checkbox.

[Here the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpTXL/)

I tried everything I can think of such as `float: right` but it just pushes the the yellow box outside

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.box   {
    background-color: #008DEF;
    color: #9C5A3C;
    height:100px;
    width:260px;
    position: relative; top:70px;
}   
.textbox
{
    background-color: #FF58C3;
    height:90px;
    width:170px;
}   
.checkbox
{
    background-color: #FFAB24;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:right;
}   
</style>
 <div class="box"> 
 <div class="textbox"> </div>
 <div class="checkbox"> </div>
 </div>


 </div>




 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `float:left` to the .textbox class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5xzCw/)**

Comment: sorry I said , it was wrong . I have too much things in my mind , going crazy thank you danield